# Extract a file from war file that is present inside ear file

Tags: unix, jar, war, ear

I want to extract a particular file that is there in the following structure.

TestApp.ear/TestApp.war/WEB-INF/web.xml

Is there any way we can extract web.xml alone using unix command?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

The `jar` command should work with `ear`, `war` and `jar`

If you know the absolute path for your file to be extracted, you can use

```
jar xf jar_file.jar <name_of_file_to_extract>

jar xvf file.ear path/to/file/file.abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. File to be extracted is present inside .war .. This command will not extract recursively